# Convert toLocalTime with format

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have a DateTime.Utcnow that I want to convert to local time. I want to convert it to local time in the format of `"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"`. ToLocalTime doesn't have a constructor for it.

```
_executionTimeRepository.SetLastSuccessfulRunDate(DateTime.UtcNow, "FailedJobService");

public void SetLastSuccessfulRunDate(DateTime successfulRunDate, string nameOfService)
{
    using (var context = _contextFactory())
    {
        var field = context.ExecutionTimes.First(s => s.NameOfService == nameOfService);
        field.LastRunDate = successfulRunDate.ToLocalTime();
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of String

```
string date1 = DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime().ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
```

In case of DateTime

```
DateTime date2 = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime().ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `field.LastRunDate` a `DateTime` or `string`? Depending on the type see options:

**if DateTime**

```
field.LastRunDate = successfulRunDate.ToLocalTime();
//and when displaying it convert to string with your format
string dateStr = field.LastRunDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
```

**if string**

```
field.LastRunDate = successfulRunDate.ToLocalTime().ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
```